# org-drill vs org-learn

Tags: org-mode, org-drill

When searched for space repetition mode for emacs org-drill is the one google lists and looks popular but org-learn is written by the current maintainer of emacs John Wiegely. Its hard to choose one over another without knowing the pros and cons of each package.

```
 Those who have tried both please list the pros and cons of both the packages?.
```

Comment: I haven't tried neither org-drill nor org-learn, but it seems the former depends on the latter.

Comment: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-07/msg01256.html
says: "org-drill", a module which uses "org-learn".

https://bitbucket.org/eeeickythump/org-drill/src/01b05cd7561ad69e5ec9c1200414d4fa128c9a17/org-drill.el?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default
org-drill.el contains (require 'org-learn).

Comment: See also: https://github.com/abo-abo/pamparam

Comment: pamparam stores metadata outside org file in a separate file. Somehow dont like this idea. Never came across any org related package that does store data and metadata separately.

Comment: It seems org-learn is a tiny package that was written as a proof of concept, which essentially has one function, `org-smart-reschedule`, that one can use to review "todo-cards" in their agenda: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-10/msg00535.html